# Why isn't the DOM getting updated when a checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkAgreement" value="Y" />
</div>
```

When do a `$("#myDiv").html()` or inspect the `chkAgreement` element in the browser, the markup doesn't get updated. I was expecting a `checked` attribute.

I need to grab the HTML and save it in the database. But I was surprised that the checkbox is not checked, even when it is - `$("#chkAgreement").is(":checked")` returns true.

What can I do to update the DOM with the proper checked attribute for the checkbox?

Should I be doing a `$("#chkAgreement").attr("checked", "checked")`, upon the user checking the box? It works, but is this the right approach or am I missing something?

Comment: I guess this is what you're looking for: [Attributes vs Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6004028/3115653). Once rendered, the info whether the checkbox is checked or not is available as a property. And on toggle the property value changes, but the DOM doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can work (if you already have jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#chkAgreement").change(function() { 
        if($(this).is(":checked")) { 
            //your code to update ...
        } else {
           // else statement ...
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Has nothing to do what OP is asking.

Answer (score -1):

#### Note:

if you're looking for a solution where you have multiple checkboxes with the same name, you checkout this [demo](https://codepen.io/hamzeen/pen/BaBPMeO). Also note that **DOM will never change once the page is rendered unless you use some modern JS framework which would do otherwise**. Therefore, we can't expect any update to the DOM based on any user interaction. @a_nain has already mentioned this.

You can do this with plain vanilla javascript:

```js
var checkA = document.getElementById("chkAgreement");

// when the page loads
window.onload = function(e){
  console.log("checkbox value onLoad: " + checkA.checked);
}    

// when the user checks or un-checks the checkbox
checkA.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log('New Value:' + checkA.checked);

  if (checkA.checked) {
   console.log('Y checked');
  } else {
    console.log('Y unchecked');
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
    <input name="agreement" type="checkbox" id="chkAgreement" value="Y"/> I agree with the terms
</div>
```

Comment: Has nothing to do what OP is asking.